# How to select the elements based on a list in numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
array([[1374495, 3, 'prior', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [3002854, 3, 'prior', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [2710558, 3, 'prior', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       ...,
       [1355976, 206200, 'prior', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree',
        'dairy eggs'],
       [1909878, 206200, 'prior', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree',
        'dairy eggs'],
       [943915, 206200, 'train', ..., 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs']], dtype=object)
```

the first number of every row is orderid, like `1374495, 3002854, 2710558...` Now I have a list of orderid which shall be used to get the rows from the array. For example, the list to be used is `[1355976, 1909878, 943915 ]`, I should select the rows from array whose orderid in `[1355976, 1909878, 943915 ]`. How can I realize this in an efficient way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach based on [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def filter_rows(a, idx):
    # a is input dataframe as array
    # idx is list of indices for selecting rows

    a_idx = a[:,0]
    idx_arr = np.sort(idx)
    pos_idx = np.searchsorted(idx_arr, a_idx)
    pos_idx[pos_idx == idx_arr.size] = 0
    mask = idx_arr[pos_idx] == a_idx
    out = a[mask]
    return out
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
a[np.in1d(a[:,0], idx)]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([[1374495, 3, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [3002854, 3, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [2710558, 3, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [1355976, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [1909878, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [943915, 206200, 'train', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs']])

In [84]: idx
Out[84]: [1355976, 1909878, 943915]

In [85]: filter_rows(a, idx)
Out[85]: 
array([[1355976, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [1909878, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [943915, 206200, 'train', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs']])

In [88]: a[np.in1d(a[:,0], idx)]
Out[88]: 
array([[1355976, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [1909878, 206200, 'prior', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs'],
       [943915, 206200, 'train', 16.0, 'soy lactosefree', 'dairy eggs']])
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains efficient functionality for these type of operations:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
row_idx = npi.indices(id_column, ids_to_get_index_of)
```

Should have the same performance as the solution offered by Divakar, but comes with some extra bells and whistles, like kwargs to select various ways of dealing with missing values, and so on.